# AngularJS Factory im doing it wrong

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to write a Factory for my WebApiCall

so ive written this :

```
mod.factory('AccountService', function($http) {
var service = {};

var onError = function(response) {
    if (response == '') {
        return ['Timeout Occured !'];
    }
    var errors = [];
    for (var key in response.ModelState) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.ModelState[key].length; i++) {
            errors.push(response.ModelState[key][i]);
        }
    }

    return errors;
};

var onSuccess = function(response) {
    return true;
}

service.Login = function(credentials) {
    $http.put('http://localhost:9239/Api/Account/', credentials).success(function(data) {
        return onSuccess(response);
    }).error(function (response) {
        return onError(response);
    });
};

return service;
```

});

The Controller :

```
mod.controller('accountCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window, $location, ConfigService, AccountService) {

$scope.credentials = { username: '', password: '' };
$scope.Errors = [];
$scope.registerModel = { username: '', password: '', passwordrepeat: '', email: '', emailrepeat: '' };
$scope.isLoading = false;

$scope.Login = function () {
    $scope.Errors = [];
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    AccountService.Login($scope.credentials).onSuccess(function(response) {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('loginToken', data.SuccessMessages[0]);
                   if (data.SuccessMessages[1] != '') {
                        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('groupId', data.SuccessMessages[1]);
                   }
                   $scope.isLoading = false;
                    $location.path('/Home');
    }).onError(function(errors) {
        $scope.Errors.push(errors);
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    });
```

Ok when i Login the Login MEthod is called. But wenn the Success or Error Method from $http is called it doesnt return my onSuccess or onError function.

I think i made some mistakes did i ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things, `$http` promises don't have `onSuccess` or `onError` callbacks, they're `sucess` and `error` instead. In your service you are not returning the `$http` promise, and then you call `sucess` and `error` on it, of course it won't work! `$http` calls, much like Ajax calls anywhere take place asynchronously, meaning that you cant simply return a value in the success/error callback, you can however return a promise:

```
service.Login = function(credentials) {
    return $http.put('http://localhost:9239/Api/Account/', credentials)
};
```

and in your controller you could use that like:

```
AccountService.Login($scope.credentials).then(function(data) {//success callback
   $window.sessionStorage.setItem('loginToken', data.SuccessMessages[0]);
    if (data.SuccessMessages[1] != '') {
       $window.sessionStorage.setItem('groupId', data.SuccessMessages[1]);
    }
    $scope.isLoading = false;
    $location.path('/Home');
},function(errors) {//error callback
    $scope.Errors.push(errors);
    $scope.isLoading = false;
})
```

when you call then on the promise, it gets executed when the promise is resolved, the first function is success callback and the second is the error callback.